# Executing timer after interval in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, timer

Hello i have a button that when clicked posts some data to my server, the data is then processed after which it returns a result.

What i want to do now is after the response is returned with no errors i want a timer to start after **5secs**, when the timer starts it should execute a function after every **1sec**.  This should go on for a **full minute** after which the timer should be **destroyed** and a function should be executed to alert the user that the operation has timed out.

I know how to execute a normal timer using $interval or $timeout but i have no idea how to do what i have described above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this ?

```
var startTimer = function () {
    // This executes functionToExecuteEverySecond every second
    var interval = $interval(function () {
        functionToExecuteEverySecond();
    }, 1000);

    // This destroys the interval promise after 60 seconds
    $timeout(function () {
        $interval.cancel(interval);
        notifyUser();
    }, 60000);
};

// This executes startTimer function after 5 seconds
$timeout(function () {
    startTimer();
}, 5000);
```

Comment: Wow this really looks like what i need, i will try it out :)

Comment: Tried it! Works exactly how i wanted it to! :)